# Is "Members" visibilty available anywhere in Videos resources in Youtube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

One of the Videos resource's properties is *status.privacyStatus*. According to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus), it can be "private", "public" or "unlisted". Those values match the possible values for the visibility of a video, except for "members", which does not seem to be available in *status.privacyStatus* property.

[Taken from Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjAkF.png)

Two questions:

1. Is it correct to assume *status.privacyStatus* is the same as the video's visibility?
2. Will "members" ever be added as a possible value to the *status.privacyStatus* property?

I was expecting to see one more value available in status.privacyStatus: "Members"

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example id of such a video.